# What is the relationship between Onto and One-to-One?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What is the relationship between one-to-one and onto? Can a one-to-one function be onto? Can an onto function be one-to-one? Must a one-to-one function be onto? Must an onto function be 1-1?

Comment: Did you do *any* research on this before asking the question? Did you at least skim the relevant Wikipedia articles? Virtually *any* elementary reference in discrete mathematics is going to have a lengthy discussion of each of these.

Comment: @thecat See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection,_injection_and_surjection

Comment: What is the difference between a commutative salamander and a distributive aardvark? If you don't understand two concepts, asking for an explanation of how they differ is not a good strategy.

Comment: Although the general sentiment is that this question seems too basic, the intent was not to use Q&A as a reference guide of definitions. Rather, the title is perhaps somewhat misleading as to the point of the question. The goal of the question was to learn about the relationship between onto and 1-1 in the context of only remembering that they are important but not much else. Thus, the idea was to get a conceptual understanding of how the two are related.

Comment: The issue is not that it's too basic, it's that it's far too broad: There are large articles and chapters of textbooks devoted to this, and the content included in the question doesn't indicate any background knowledge.

Comment: Is that more specific?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To explain this, it helps to have a list of the "parts of a function".

There are three main "parts" to a function $f:A \to B$.

1. The domain (this is $A$).
2. The co-domain (this is $B$, and it is *different* than the "range").
3. The rule (this tells us which $b \in B$ any $a \in A$ maps to, which we indicate by writing $b = f(a)$.)

There are two other "kinds" of sets that are useful for describing a function $f: A \to B$.

If $X \subseteq A$, we have the set $f(X) = \{y \in B: y = f(x), x \in X\}$, called the *image set* of $X$. If $X$ has just one element in it, say $X = \{a_0\}$, then so does $f(X) = \{f(a_0)\}$. But functions can send more than one domain element to the same co-domain element, for example the function:

$f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ with the rule $f(x) = x^2$, sends both $2$ and $-2$ to $4$.

The other kind of useful set is called a *pre-image set*: if $Y \subset B$, we have:

$f^{-1}(Y) = \{x \in A: f(x) \in Y\}$.

If $f$ is the squaring function on the reals I gave above, we have $f^{-1}(\{4\}) = \{-2,2\}$.

Now any function maps singleton sets *to* singleton sets. We say a function is one-to-one if the pre-image $f^{-1}$ (which is defined on SUBSETS of $B$) maps singletons to singletons (hence the name "one-to-one"). This is the same as saying any domain element maps to a co-domain element that NO OTHER domain element maps to.

We say a function is *onto* if $B = f(A)$ (that is, any $b \in B$ has a pre-image in $A$).

It is possible for a function to be both one-to-one AND onto, such a function is then called a "one-to-one correspondence" or *bijection*. For example, the function:

$g: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ given by $g(x) = x+1$ is both:

If $g(x) = g(y)$, then $x + 1 = y + 1 \implies x = y$, so each real number is mapped under $g$ to a unique image no other real number is mapped to.

On the other hand, given $a \in \Bbb R$, we have $a - 1 \in \Bbb R$, and $g(a - 1) = (a - 1) + 1 = a$, so any real number is realizable as the image of some other real number under $g$.

The squaring function I gave above is neither one-to-one nor onto (no negative real numbers are in the image). The function:

$h: \Bbb Z \to \Bbb Z$ given by $h(n) = 2n$ is one-to-one, but not onto.

The function $k: \Bbb R \to \{1\}$ given by $k(x) = 1$ is onto, but certainly *not* one-to-one.

Answer (score 3):

Onto function:

A function $f$ from $A$ to $B$ is called onto if for all $b$ in $B$ there is an $a$ in $A$ such that $f (a) = b$.   All elements in $B$ are used.

1-1 function:

A function $f$ from $A$ to $B$ is called one-to-one (or 1-1) if whenever
 $f (a) = f (b)$ then $a = b$.   No element of $B$ is the image of more than one element in $A$.

Onto functions could be 1-1 functions, and 1-1 functions could also be onto functions.

[You may find this website useful](http://www.regentsprep.org/regents/math/algtrig/atp5/OntoFunctions.htm)

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to think about injectivity (one-to-one), surjectivity (onto), and bijectivity (one-to-one and onto) of a mapping $f$ between sets $f : A \to B$, is to consider the number of preimages of $x \in B$ under $f$.  For each $x \in B$,

Injective:  $x$ has at **most** one preimage in $A$.

Surjective:  $x$ has at **least** one preimage in $A$.

Bijective:  $x$ has **exactly** one preimage in $A$.

Answer (score 0):

Onto = Surjective, i.e. every element in the codomain is mapped by some element in the domain

One-to-one = Injective, i.e. no two distinct elements in the domain are mapped to the same element in the codomain

Those two properties are independent. If a function is one-to-one and onto, it is called a bijection.

*PS: please use Google next time; looking up the definition of those two terms would have immediately given you the answer*

Answer (score 0):

A function is onto (or surjective) iff every element of its codomain is the image of at least one element of the domain, and it is one to one (or injective) if there are no two different elements of the domain that have the same image